# Can I use a cursor to select two rows and compare attributes

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, update, cursor

Can I use the cursor search function to look at the first two rows in a table and select them so I can compare attributes and possibly merge them or change attributes? I am using ArcGIS 10.0

Comment: Well you could just iterate through the first two records of the cursor's results and save the first one to local variables, then move to the next variable, and compare the two.

Comment: How would that look in code? Im used to coding in VB and not as familiar with python

Comment: If you search the Desktop Help file for SearchCursor you will find several examples of how to use them. Desktop help always has examples of varying degrees of complexity, it's the first place you should always look. The fact you are asking this question suggests you have not look at these...

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000

That's how it would look using ArcPy  (you should note, on the side in the table of contents on that page, there are also links to update and insert cursors if you need to actually edit the data as well as just search it.)